# SoapUI: Transfer groovy script results using Property Transfer

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am an absolute noob in SoapUI. I am looking out for answer on this but somehow could not really find it.

I am in a situation where I would like to transfer two of the groovy scripts's results  to another Groovyscript. Unfortunately, while using Property Transfer, the destined groovy script gets fully overriden by the return value by the source script. How shall I approach this?

Please find below the example for the same:
[image]

As you may see, I would like to pass the value of the transferred result of `generateCreated` and `generateNonce` to the `generatePassword` script in `testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Nonce")` and `testRunner.testCase.getPropertyValue("Created")`
But this just doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a Property Transfer teststep for that.

You just let your first two scripts run - as you already are doing.

Then in your third Groovy Script, you just pull the results into variables.

This can be done using something like

```
def result = context.expand( '${Groovy Script#result}' )
```

In your case above, I suspect you would adjust that to something like

```
def created = context.expand( '${generateCreated#result}' )
def nonce = context.expand( '${generateNonce#result}' )
```

Insert those lines in your script whereever you need those variables, and then you have the variables "created" and "nonce" holding the results.